# Releasing optional containing std::function during call to that function

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++20

I've got a question that I can't seem to find a definitive answer on in the standard. I'm looking to know if what I'm doing here is well defined (and thus can be relied on)

I've got a class that represents a thread and within that class there's a member

```cpp
std::optional<std::function<void()>> ops;
```

Every so often when the thread isn't busy executing other code it will check if `ops` has a value and if it does it will execute it. (With appropriate locking).

What I am wondering is: is it well-defined behavior to call `ops.clear()` from the function that is currently loaded into `ops`.

Here's a more illustrative example, without threading but still keeping locking:

```cpp
class ops_t
{
  private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::optional<std::function<void()>> ops;
  public:
    void set_ops(std::function<void()> new_ops)
    {
      std::lock_guard guard(mutex);
      ops = new_ops;
    }

    void clear_ops()
    {
      std::lock_guard guard(mutex);
      ops.reset();
    }

    void do_ops()
    {
      std::optional<std::function<void()>> ops_local = [this]() // make copy so we don't hold mutex while executing
      {
        std::lock_guard guard(mutex);
        return ops;
      }();
      if(ops_local)
        (*ops_local)();
    }
};


int main(void)
{
  ops_t ops;
  ops.set_ops(std::bind_front(&ops_t::clear_ops, &ops));
  ops.do_ops(); // is the sequence of events triggered here well defined by the standard?
}
```

Post [self-destroy std::function during call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155850/self-destroy-stdfunction-during-call) does not answer my question. The accepted answer there goes on a long tangent about pointers to the object being deleted; however I do not have that issue.

Compiling this code works and running it doesn't result in a segmentation fault; however this situation is rather odd and thus I'm trying to confirm it's well defined by the c++20 standard

Comment: `std::function` is no different from any other object.  If you destroy it while it's being used there's a high chance its members will be accessed after they're destroyed, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @MilesBudnek that's a very fair point. I'll try with valgrind's use-after-free-checking

Comment: Both valgrind and asan do not report use-after-free issues; however this does not definitively mean that a use-after-free isn't occurring.

Comment: this might not be UB since you don't use any of the object after you have destroyed it.  If you had used the object it would certainly be UB.  This kind of code makes me very leery and I would try to find a workaround or redesign of some sort.

Comment: Not that you are not invoking `ops`. You are invoking `ops_local`, and clearing `ops` does not affect `ops_local`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not do what you think it does.

Your code makes a stack local copy of the std function then runs it.  While running it, it destroys the class copy of the function object (in an `optional`).

Those two objects are unrelated (well, one is a copy of the other), so no lifetime issues entail.

So the code you posted is safe.

If you actually did what the rest of your question asks about, I believe your code would be acting outside the bounds of the standard's defined behaviour.

Last I checked, std function makes no guarantees it does not touch its own state after its owned `operator()` runs.  It probably could make that guarantee, but the wording would be awkward.

So most (but not all) std function implementations will survive *if* the last operation that touches the function object's state destroys the std function, but your code would still be considered exhibiting UB for being in a method of a destroyed std object.